# Pass navbar id to store function of other controller

Tags: laravel

how can I pass ID from navbars table to MenuitemController?

I have 2 tables in relationship: Navbar 1 : N Menuitem. In the navbar list I have a button that goes to the menuitem list:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('navbar/' . $nav->id )}}" class="btn-secondary btn-sm" style="width: 30px; height:30px;"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

```
public function show(NavbarRepository $navRepo, $id){
        $navbar = $navRepo->find($id);
        $menuItems = $navbar->menuitems()->get();
        return view('pages.navbar.show', [
            "navbar" => $navbar,
            "menuItems" => $menuItems
        ]);
    }
```

and now I have an empty list of items in a particular navbar, there I have a button to create a new item (menuitem)

Create new
Here is MenuitemController:

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.menuitem.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $menuitem = Menuitem::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->action('NavbarController@nlist');
    }
```

and part of create.blade.php (menuitem):

```
 <input type="hidden" name="navbar_id" id="navbar_id"/>
but this navbar_id is empty. How can I pass this variable here?
```

Route:

```
//Navbar
Route::get('navbar/{id}', 'NavbarController@show');
//Menuitem
Route::get('menuitem/create','MenuitemController@create')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('menuitem/', 'MenuitemController@store')->middleware('auth');
```

Button to generate URL:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/navbar/'. $navbar->id. '/menuitem/' . $item->id )}}" class="btn-primary btn-sm">SHOW</a>
```

Thanks for help!

---

EDIT:
ok I have now:

```
 <a href="{{ URL::to('navbar/' .$navbar->id. '/menuitem/create') }}"
           class="btn btn-success pull-right">New menu item</a>
```

and it build route:

```
localhost/navbar/1/menuitem/create
```

but after redirect to this route I don't have navbar id. Should I pass it now to controller?

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.menuitem.create');
    }
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $menuitem = Menuitem::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->action('NavbarController@nlist');
    }
```

Create.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ action ('MenuitemController@store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }}"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="navbar_id" id="navbar_id"/>
  <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <label for="url">Adres URL:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="URL" id="url" maxlength="999" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

Comment: how did you define this route to the `create` method?

Comment: you need to be passing something to this `create` method (as an input or route parameter) so it can include that id in the form in the view it is returning

Comment: I understand that, but i don't know how can I pass navbar's id :(

Comment: how are you generating a URL to this `create` method? there is no view that is generating links to it in your post, can you show that view

Comment: I added this button now, but there is an error. After hover I see only URL: localhost/navbar/1

Comment: that path you are building doesn't match the route for that `create` method ... show the view where you are generating a link to the `create` method which returns the form with the hidden input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function create($navbar_id)
{
    return view('pages.menuitem.create', ['navbar_id' => $navbar_id]);
}

<input type="hidden" name="navbar_id" id="navbar_id" value="{{ $navbar_id }}" />
```

Comment: after test, navbar_id in DB is empty :/

Comment: did you set that field fillable on that model?